# Cannot connect to remote AWS Linux MySQL from local Windows machine

Tags: mysql, linux

I have a MySQL database server on a remote AWS Linux Machine. I can access this server by SSH. 
However, I need to access this from my Windows computer and it's not working (using mysql -u root -p -h remoteAddress where remoteAddress in the IP address of my remote server). I also have a local MySQL server installed so mysql -u root -p -h localhost on Windows works normally.

I have read a lot on this but no solutions are working for me. The error I'm getting is:

**Error 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'remoteAddress' (10060)**

Now I have bind-address commented out in my my.cnf file and in addition using phpmyadmin, I can confirm that root can be accessed from anywhere (i.e. it says from %).

Even if I turn off the iptables service, I still get the same error.

Furthemore, if I type in netstat -tln | grep 3306, I get:

```
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:3306 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN
```

I don't care about the safety implications presently, I just want to get this working.

Comment: first check if your mysql is running on default port 3306 or else then check if you are using public DNS/IP to connect it remotely or else.

Comment: even your first step should be to check mysql connectivity from localhost means first connect your EC2 instance from putty and connect mysql if your are able to connect locally then you should try to connect remotely......one more thing after commented bind address did you restarted mysql service.

Comment: Then check if the remote server is configured to accept connections remotely. You may have to tunnel the mysql connection through ssh.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. SSH was working fine because SSH traffic was allowed from the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the comments on my question I had an idea which led me to the solution. Everything on the server was set up properly except that AWS places a level of security on top of things which needs to be changed.

I simply added MySQL to the list of inbound traffic allowed in the security group settings and that solved it. I should have done this when creating the instance but didn't know that I would be using MySQL on the server at the time. 
So I modified the security group to add MySQL traffic.

I know this was a really niche problem but I hope it helps someone if they find themselves in the same situation.

Comment: You should accept you're own answer and mention that you modified the security group.

Comment: I wanted to accept my own answer but stack overflow said I have to wait two days. I will add the security group info however.